# Where is $f(z)$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider $f(z)=g(z)/(1-z^{-1})$ where

- $g(z)$ is analytic for $z\neq 0$
- $g(z)$ has a zero at $z=1$
- $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=1$

Is $\ln f(z)$ analytic inside the unit circle? Is it analytic on the unit circle?

My thinking is this: it is analytic on the unit circle with $z=1$ excluded, and it is analytic inside the unit circle with $z=0$ excluded. Is is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$f(z)=\frac{zg(z)}{z-1}$$

At $z=0$, if $g$ has a simple pole there, then $f(z)$ does not have pole there, and thus $\ln f$ does not have a branch point there. Otherwise, $z=0$ is a branch point of $\ln f$.

At $z=1$, if $g$ has a simple zero there, then, $f$ is non zero there, implying $z=1$ is not a branch point of $\ln f$. Otherwise, $f$ is zero there, implying $\ln f$ has a branch point there.

The choice of branch cut determines where $\ln f$ is non analytic inside the unit circle.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.